# Como remover os espaços antes e depois de uma string sem o método "trim()" do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

estou com esse código para remover os primeiros e os ultimos espaços porem ele esta removendo todos os espacos presentes.

Segue:

```js
const separador = ' ';

function filtro(separador, str) {
  let resultado = '';
  let stringNova = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === separador) {
      resultado += str[i];
    } else {
        stringNova += str[i];
    }
  }

  return stringNova;
}


console.log(filtro(separador, ("  X DSA   ")));
```

Deveria retornar:

`X DSA` e não `XDSA`.

Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

**Pessoal, na real eu estou criando um metodo Trim meu mesmo, por isso nao quero usar o metodo Trim do proprio JS**

Comment: +1 por várias razões

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela sua ideia precisaria parar o for ao encontrar o "primeiro não separador" e começar um novo de trás pra frente, seguindo a mesma ideia.

Me empolguei fazendo aqui.. veja se isso atende :P

```
function MeuTrim(pTexto){
    var letra = pTexto[0];

    if (pTexto.length > 0){
        while (letra == ''){
            if (pTexto.length == 1)
                pTexto = '';

            pTexto = pTexto.substr(1);
            letra = pTexto[0];
        }

        if (pTexto.length > 0){
            letra = pTexto[pTexto.length - 1];
            while (letra == ''){
                if (pTexto.length == 1)
                    pTexto = '';

                pTexto = pTexto.substr(0, pTexto.length - 2);
                letra = pTexto[pTexto.length - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return pTexto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Não vejo necessidade de reinventar a roda, o `Javascript` já possui uma função nativa para realizar isso e ela já está "homologada" e testada.

Segue abaixo exemplo com método [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```js
console.log(("  X DSA   ").trim());
```

Comment: +1 por várias razões

Comment: +1 também, seguindo os princípios do grande Uncle Bob! :D

Answer (score 5):

Pode-se usar a regex:

```
/^\s+|\s+$
```

Onde:

- `^`     identifica o comeco do texto
- `\s`    identifica espacos
- `|`     ou
- `$`     final do texto

**Exemplo**

```js
function fazerTrim(string) {
  return string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

console.log(fazerTrim("  X DSA   "));
```